# Only show button-A when button-B is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use jQuery to show a button when an other button is displayed. But I'm not that of a jQuery expert. So I was wondering if there would be anyone that could help me with this one?

I have 2 buttons:

- Button `ent-step`
- Button `del-step`

What I want to do is to only show button `ent-step` when button `del-step` is on screen. Normally this button `del-step` is hidden with this JavaScript:

```
function showDellocation($this) {
    var dataLocation = $this.attr("data-location");
        $(".del-step[data-location='" + dataLocation + "']").show();
        $(".add-step[data-location='" + dataLocation + "']").addClass( "blur" );
    }
function hideDellocation($this) {
    var dataLocation = $this.attr("data-location");
        $this.hide();
        $(".add-step[data-location='" + dataLocation + "']").removeClass("blur");
}
```

The button `ent-step` is in an other PHP file called by Ajax:

```
<table class="item-buttons">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:150px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:150px;">
            <a href="example.com/step" value="Ent">
                <button class="ent-step">Entertainment&nbsp;
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true">/i>
                </button>
            </a>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can I use the `blur` class to activate this option? For instance:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
    if ($(this).hasClass('blur')) {
        $('.ent-step').addClass('clickable');
    }
```

And then style the button using CSS?
Or is this not the correct way to do this?

Comment: I don't see `ent-step` in your code.

Comment: Just after $(".del-step[data-location='" + dataLocation + "']").show(); u can show **ent-step** like $(".ent-step").show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show hide the button based on `class` of `.add-step`

```
if ($('.add-step').hasClass('blur')) {
    $('.ent-step').show();
}
```

And when you are hiding the `.add-step` hide the `.ent-step` button as well

```
function hideDellocation($this) {
   var dataLocation = $this.attr("data-location");
   $this.hide();
   $(".add-step[data-location='" + dataLocation + "']").removeClass("blur");
   $('.ent-step').hide();
}
```